# How to avoid boxing and if or Switch statements

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, generics

Suppose I have following object:

```
object[] objs = new object[3]{ "this is sample string", 42L, 1};
```

and I want to do something to the individual objects in the array like

```
foreach (object o in objs)
{
   /// logic here 
     mylogic();
}
```

Now `mylogic()` will only take object parameters so there is boxing going on, but we require to be able to do something based on the type of the object, so we would do something like :

```
public void dosomething(object obj)
{ 
   // one way
   if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
   {
      // string specific something
   }
   // another way
   if(obj is long)
   {
      // long specific something
   }

}
```

Well it's ugly and non performance, is there a better way possible using generics or any other way?

Comment: The ugly started on the object[] objs = new object[3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are already boxed, because they are stored in an `object[]`. So no additional boxing takes place when you pass them to a method taking an `object` argument.

The `object[]` is where I would aim my focus - is it really necessary to represent your data like that? Do you really not know their structure? It would be preferable to define a class (or a structure) to hold your data, and also to contain the methods that act on the data - then you know a type of each field or property at design and compile time, and you can use this information in further code. In your case that might look like:

```
class Container
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public long LongProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // string specific something with StringProperty
        // long specific something with LongProperty
        // int specific something with IntProperty
    }
}
```

That way you begin to *encapsulate* your data and make sure it is located close to the logic that uses them. Even better might be to make the properties into private readonly fields, so they are not even visible to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into using the dynamic keyword in C# 4.0 and later and see if that helps you.  It would be better to define your own class and make properties of the different types and just use those instead.

The memory overhead would be minimal and you'd avoid all the boxing penalties.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, in such cases one should ask the question: is there anything wrong with the code design? What is the idea of the array containing different types of objects? What do they represent? May be you need a separate class that holds these different objects...